# Trouble trying to make these tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I'm running into an issue while trying to create these 5 tables. From what I can tell the issue has to deal with the champ. Every time I try to import my sql file I get an errno 150 stating that the champion table cannot be created.

To clarify a champion can only have one faction but a faction can be composed of many champions. The same relationship for roles and affinity. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `champion`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `role`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `build`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `faction`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `build_type`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `affinity`;


-- roles table 
-- Table consisting of the roles various champions play

CREATE TABLE `role` (
        `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `role_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- build table
CREATE TABLE `build` (
        `build_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `build_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`build_id`),
        UNIQUE KEY (`build_name`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- faction table 
-- Table consisting of the faction each champion belongs to

CREATE TABLE `faction`(
        `faction_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `faction_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`faction_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- Champions table 
-- Table consisting of various champions in League of Legends

CREATE TABLE `champion`(
        `champion_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `champion_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `f_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
         `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`champion_id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`r_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`role_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
        FOREIGN KEY (`f_id`) REFERENCES `faction` (`faction_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `affinity` (`affinity_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        UNIQUE KEY (`champion_name`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- build_type table 
CREATE TABLE `build_type`(
        `cid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        `bid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`cid`, `bid`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `champion` (`champion_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES `build` (`build_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


-- affinity table 
-- Table consisting of the affinity a certain champion synergizes
-- with

CREATE TABLE `affinity`(
        `affinity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `affinity_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`affinity_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `champion` table has a column `a_id` referring to a table `affinity` that does not exist yet.To solve this problem you must first create the `affinity` table before `champion` table

This

```
CREATE TABLE `affinity`(
        `affinity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `affinity_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`affinity_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

must come before

```
CREATE TABLE `champion`(
        `champion_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `champion_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `f_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
         `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`champion_id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`r_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`role_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
        FOREIGN KEY (`f_id`) REFERENCES `faction` (`faction_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `affinity` (`affinity_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        UNIQUE KEY (`champion_name`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I'm glad it was such an easy fix. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.